# On Windows Desktop Sharing API, UAC prompt becomes black pause screen

Tags: c++, windows, uac, rdp

I want to make remote assistance like application, using Windows Desktop Sharing API.

[MSDN Blog says](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/03/08/windows-desktop-sharing-api.aspx),

> What is the behavior when "Secure Desktop" pops up while sharing?
>   "Pause screen- Black screen with two bars(indicating pause) at lower right" is remoted when secure desktop (UAC prompts) is up on sharer's machine, when sharing process is run as a non-system process.

Yes, that is my problem. How to avoid black pause screen?
I read [UAC Group Policy Settings and Registry Key Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), and it seems the answer.
I have tried
* Set the Group policy "User Account Control: Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop" -> ENABLED on both machines.
* Set Visual Studio's property "/uiAccess='true'" for the application.
* Make my own root certificate using "makecert", and install it. Also, make chained certificate for the application, and install it.
* Sign to the application using "signtool".
* Put the application under "Program Files" sub direcroty.

But still I see a black pause screen...

**ADDITION**
The MS Remote Assistance has a checkbox "Allow HELPER respond to User Account Control prompts", and it avoids black pause screen.
But I cannot find corresponding API or settings.
Does anyone know about this?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming, exactly?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, starting point was [Windows Desktop Sharing API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I couldn't control UAC by the API...

Answer (score 1):

Reason: UAC is run in a different, privileged session (think of it as another user just logged in) which is not accessible from any screen-sharing program of the current user.

Solution: Disable UAC. There is no other way.

Comment: That is too dangerous solution to accept. Do we have only this solution?

Comment: The MS Remote Assistance has a dialog "Allow HELPER respond to User Account Control prompts", and helper can operate UAC. There must be a way...